# Start jar in cmd with spaces

Tags: java, windows, path, cmd

i'm in windows 7, and i try to start this command in cmd

> java -jar C:\Dropbox\Java\Updater Test\Updater.jar

The file exists, but i had this error:

> Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Dropbox\Java\Updater

I also try to:

> java -jar C:\Dropbox\Java\Updater%20Test\Updater.jar

But doesn't work

Comment: Put quotes around C:\

Comment: `java -jar "C:\Dropbox\Java\Updater Test\Updater.jar"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the path in quotes so that the entire path is treated as a single command-line parameter.

Answer (score 5):

try

```
java -jar "C:\Dropbox\Java\Updater Test\Updater.jar"
```